# How to prevent Maven Surefire from running Spring integration tests automatically

Tags: java, spring, maven, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

My integration tests take long to run, and I don't want my developers to waste time every time they need to compile. I only want my integration tests to run:

- In my CI/CD server.
- When I tell my IDE (NetBeans) to specifically run a test file.

Is this possible? How can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you seen [_Integration Testing with Maven_](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-integration-test) already?

Comment: The linked article also violates convention over configuration. Using conventions is easier...

Answer (score 0):

Add a configuration to your POM that excludes the integration tests during your normal build (assuming that your integration tests are named something like `UserService_IT.java`.

```
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skip.surefire.tests}</skipTests>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*_IT*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
```

To run the integration tests, say in your CI build, add a profile and activate it in your pipeline, like `mvn verify -Pintegration-tests`.

```
<profile>
  <id>integration-tests</id>
  <activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    <property>
      <name>integration-tests</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*_IT.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: For unit test the default naming schema is `*Test.java`, `Test*.java` etc.  see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes. and for integration test the default naming schema is `*IT.java` etc. see https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes so there is no need to define includes/excludes nor a property for skipping unit tests. And also I would recommend to make a integration test profiles which will simply being activated by using `mvn -Prun-its` and not using a a profile with activeByDefault...

Comment: Follow convention over configuration paradigm.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I was under the assumption that the conventions were not followed as he stated they were always running.  Note that the profile in the above example is not activeByDefault and is activated on `verify` or `integration-test` given that it's been activated.

Comment: No the profile is not automatically activated only via `-Dintegration-tests` instead of `-P...`. Mixing properties with profiles. You have to manually define that..which can be removed. Simply define a profile which can be activated by `-Prun-its`... remove the activation block...